# tmux search is sensitive to line wrap. Can I disable this?

Tags: tmux

When I size my terminal window so a long line is wrapped like:

```
-----------
|      hel|
|lo       |
|>        |
-----------
```

and search backwards for "hello" in copy mode nothing is found.
When I resize my terminal window like:

```
-------------
|      hello|
|>          |
-------------
```

and search backwards "hello" is found.

This makes search almost useless for me. Is it expected behavior for tmux? screen doesn't have this problem. How can I make search insensitive to line wrap? A plugin?

system: tmux 1.8-5; xfce terminal emulator 0.6.3; zsh; empty .tmux.conf

Comment: can this help? if it is tell me to post it as an answer http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/zooming-tmux-panes/

Comment: I don't think zooming panes will help because even in the zoomed in case some of the same words can be wrapped.However, zooming is suggestive of disabling line wrap. If tmux allows disabling line wrap, you could toggle off and on line wrap before and after searching. Maybe there's a macro that does this automatically?

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution, @SII_of_SII?

Comment: Based on this github issue I'm assuming this is a long term bug in tmux with low priority https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/966 - I get around it by capturing output via less or tee and avoiding the tmux search feature entirely.

Answer (score 0):

tmux search now works with line wrap. Some time in the last 7 years this must have changed.